# How to consume HTTP Server Sent Events in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, server-sent-events

I need to connect to an HTTP server and subscribe to a [Server Sent Event (SSE)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) source using Ruby (not Rails).

The only gems I've found that support this are [em-eventsource](https://github.com/af83/em-eventsource) (which is [horribly broken](https://github.com/af83/em-eventsource/issues/12)), and [sse-client-ruby](https://github.com/conjurinc/sse-client-ruby) which seems to be a bare fragment that requires unspecified extra plumbing in order to work.

Is there another Ruby gem that I could use? Or, could someone provide a simple home-grown example of consuming SSE events in Ruby?

Comment: The event stream protocol is simple, it shouldn't be that hard to write a parser yourself. See  [Parsing an event stream](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#event-stream-interpretation). I'm voting to close this one as you are merely asking for a gem or tutorial.

Comment: @stefan Parsing it is only half the job. I have to start receiving the stream first. Besides, aren't tutorials part of the purpose of this site?

Comment: @stefan no, seriously, how is this question off-topic?

Comment: I voted to close it because of [help/on-topic]: _"4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: I was asking how to DO something. If that's off-topic, then you might as well close the damn site and have done with it.

Comment: It's just a _vote_, nothing more, nothing less. Your question has not been closed, neither has it been down-voted. What's the problem?